# Finite dimension of space spanned by translation by AN INTEGER

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, vector-spaces

Let $E$ be the space of bounded continuous functions $\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$. For $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we note $f_k(x) = f(x-k)$.

Find all $f \in E$ such that $\mathrm{Span} \left\{ f_k, k \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$ is of finite dimension.

Note that this question is very similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237914/finite-dimensional-vector-spaces-of-functions-left-invariant-by-translation) but here we only consider translation by **an integer**. Many of those solutions require a sense of continuity of $k \mapsto f_k$ (when $k \in \mathbb{R}$), which is not possible now.

Do you have any solution that may link this problem with the latter or a new solution ?

Comment: If $f$ is periodic with integer period, then it will be finite dimensional. I guess these are all.